# How to put data frame in R including count of complete cases in separate files

Tags: r

I'm a new student at R. I have a directory containing EXCEL files and I need to make a summary in a data frame with complete cases in each file. How can I do this. I tried the following code buwt doesn't work. Appreciate your support

Comment: please post code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

Always begin with the steps required. You will need to do the following:

1. Read in your data
2. Clean up your data

Since you do not have any code shown, I will provide you with pseudo code.

```html
library(readxl)

df <- read_xls(path, other options)

df <- complete.cases(df)
```

You'll want to do that for all of your files. You can use lapply once you are more advanced, and loop over your list.files() list of excel files.

Comment: Thanks and Appreciate your support :)